# Copy and Paste one Cell at a time from a list to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i am a novice when it comes to VBA and would like some help.

I am trying to copy one cell at a time from one sheet to to another. The reason for this is because I want to copy one cell (account #) from a list (sheet "List") and paste into a predefined cell is another sheet ("Analysis") and run code that will extract data from a program. i want to then repeat this process for all the account #s in that list until the list ends. The # of accounts in this list will change periodically. Account # will always be entered into Cell "F2"

The code i am using to extract data is,

```
Range("F2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.Run "'Option holding.xls'!SecurityDistribution"
```

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with Loops?  This is exactly what you're trying to do by iterating through each cell.  You could use a For Each loop, or a For Loop.  It would be helpful for you to also find the last row dynamically, which would become part of your loop, e.g. For i = 2 to LastRow, where you have defined the last row variable.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list and call the macro

```
    Sub Do_It()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range, LstRw As Long
    Dim F1 As Range, c As Range

    Set Sh = Sheets("Transaction Analysis")
    Set F1 = Sh.Range("F1")
    Set ws = Sheets("List")
    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            F1.Value = c
            MsgBox "Call Macro Here"
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```